# How do I upgrade MySQL from 5.5 to 5.7 via SSH

Tags: mysql, upgrade, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.7

I am trying to upgrade MySQL on my VPS server.  I have root access, but whne I try to run the following commands it says that it is not in the YUM repository.

sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-{version-number}.noarch.rpm (obviously replacing with the correct version number(

sudo yum install mysql-community-server

Then I get this message.

No package mysql-community-server available.
Error: Nothing to do

Any help would be great.

Comment: What yum repos are configured on your VPC? Can you see mysql with a different name when you run `yum search mysql`?

Comment: This is the nysql yum repo that I found in there.   mysql-community-release.noarch

Comment: Anyone have more info?